# What is the location of the Python tools for Visual Studio?

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

For Microsoft Windows 10 Visual Studio 2015, what is the location on the hard drive where the Python tools for visual studio installs? I assume it should be C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Python, however I see no folder named Python or Python tools or anything like that under Visual Studio's directory even though I just installed Python tools. It also wont let me create python projects and says I still need to install the tools. I just need to know where the files should be for the python support. Thanks.

ps: Been having plenty of trouble with other VS components too. It didn't even install correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the MSBuild folder instead

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Python Tools

Answer (score 1):

This is under the MS build folder , and your environments related python folders from inside the project lib folder itself

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Python Tools

Comment: Thank's for your answer, it was perfect, unfourtunetly i can only accept one so I had to accept Abhiram since he was a bit earlier but +1 for the help :D